# Converting static text to fetch from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a hundreds of text fields that have static text as of now, since the text undergoes lot of changes and thereby difficult to maintain, I have created a table in MYSQL and have uploaded all those values in the table. I would like to fetch the loaded values,however I'm not able to think of any scalable way. Would gurus please give any suggestions:

Let me give some more details. The values are currently stored like this in a text file, and have been moved to mysql.

```
$lang = array();

$myDetail['name']           = "Tom Stephens";
$myDetail['age']            = "23";
$myDetail['address']        = "Sydney, Aus";
$myDetail['villageName']    = "No Village";
```

I would like to fetch every value now from database using php connection such as

```
select text from myDetailsTable where fieldName ='name'
select text from myDetailsTable where fieldName ='age'

select text from myDetailsTable where fieldName ='address'
select text from myDetailsTable where fieldName ='villageName'
```

The above query ensures that there is only one row to be sent back. I need to send the results of the query in each attribute.
I know how to fetch results from mysql using php, but not sure what could be the best way to pass results to these attributes.

```
$mysqli->query($query)
```

can someone share the best approach.

Comment: What prevents you from using a single query with muliple where conditions?

Comment: because all these fields to be displayed on the front end.

Comment: What do you mean by "to be displayed on the front end"?Can you add a samples of database records and db table structure?I think you can optimize your performance by tuning DB structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql  `or`, `and`  :-

```
select text from myDetailsTable 
where fieldName ='name' or fieldName ='age'
or fieldName ='address' or fieldName ='villageName'
```

Comment: this won't work for my test case, as I have tied up these text fields to UI

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you want

Comment: I need to replace the static text i.e Tom Stephens by pulling the data from database, but the problem is that there are too many fields and I would like to avoid writing one query for every step.so, thinking if I could get another approach

Comment: $sql='select text from myDetailsTable where 1=1'; 
if(isset($myDetail['name'])){
$sql .=' or fieldName ='.$myDetail['name'];
}
if(isset($myDetail['age'])){
$sql .=' or fieldName ='.$myDetail['age'];
}

Comment: i think this idea help you for creat custom query @user4943236

Comment: so do `select name, value from ... ` instead. you DON'T have to run multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

Improving @Rahautos anwser

```
select fieldName ,text from myDetailsTable 
where fieldName ='name' or fieldName ='age'
or fieldName ='address' or fieldName ='villageName'
```

You can select both fieldName and text at once.Then access values.

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if($row['fieldName'] == 'name') {
        //bind 'Name' value to ui
    }
    //Rest of the logic
}
```